# Nvidia-340 legacy driver for GeForce 210 graphics card (Ubuntu 21.04)

Tags: drivers, 20.04, nvidia, graphics

I have installed the legacy driver [Nvidia-340](https://launchpad.net/%7Ekelebek333/+archive/ubuntu/nvidia-legacy?field.series_filter=focal) for my old GeForce 210 graphics card and I got this error during installation:

```
dpkg error version '-' has bad syntax revision number is empty
dpkg error version '-' has bad syntax revision number is empty
```

The installation was completed, but after reboot the system, the screen is black with no cursor.

The kernel is 5.11.0-40-generic.

Thanks,

Comment: Looks like it didn't work. Contact the author and ask for help.

Comment: Thanks, I'll do that.